# When I attempt to insert data to my connected database it shows another database and raises an error

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

In Django, when I attempt to insert data to my connected database it shows another database and raises an error.

- I connect to database 'test'.
- Then I create tables using Python.
- Then I drop all tables in Navicat.
- Then I change connection to database 'books'.
- Then I do the same action.

I get this error:

```
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'test'")
```

[image]

**My settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'books',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'1234',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306'

    }
}

from books.models import Publisher
p1 = Publisher(name='Apress', address='2855 Telegraph Avenue',
...     city='Berkeley', state_province='CA', country='U.S.A.',
...     website='http://www.apress.com/')
p1.save()
```

Comment: Make sure you have saved and changes to files and restarted your server.

Comment: thy,i find i need to restart py manage shell